# How can I load remote data into select2 from breezejs with knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, jquery-select2

I am working on a SPA using durandaljs and breezejs to contact the database for data.  I want to use a select2 search box to search for specific personnel.  The personnel table has over 30k rows, so I can't simply load all of that data at once.  I am currently following this example, http://jsfiddle.net/anasnakawa/6XvqX/381/, specifically the select data via ajax example, but I am having trouble with the data retrieval part (ajax).  I don't think I need to do it that way since I am using breezejs.  Currently to get the data I need I would do something like:

`dataservice.getPersonnelsWithFilter(skip, take, searchTerm, searchTermChanged).then(function (data) { ... });`

skip = number of rows to skip
take = number of rows to take
searchTerm = term that I am searching for
searchTermChanged = determines if the searchTerm has changed

Comment: Your question answers itself - it is correct.  What is your question if that is not it?

Comment: For some reason I cannot load the link you give but look here http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ the "Loading Data" example - basically you will load the data inside the `query` method and call the `callback` method passing the data you got from the server.